# Cannot get store record field value in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2, store

When I attempt to find a record in an ArrayStore using Sencha Touch 2, no records are returned.

```
store.findExact('Symbol', 'GOOG')
```

returns -1.

As shown in the screenshot below,

```
store.getRange()
```

returns 44 records, and

```
store.first()
```

returns a record, but

```
store.first().get('Ask')
```

returns undefined.

Additionally, when I do

```
store.getAt(1).getData()
```

I get an object only containing the field 'id: "ext-record-2"'.

Why can I not retrieve records using store.findExact(), and why does record.get('column') return undefined?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...

I was trying to reuse a model across ExtJS and Sencha Touch applications. Sencha Touch expects "fields" to be defined inside "config," whereas ExtJS does not.

ExtJS:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'Symbol',    type: 'string'},
    {name: 'LastPrice', type: 'float'},
    {name: 'Bid',       type: 'float'},
    {name: 'Ask',       type: 'float'},
    {name: 'Volume',    type: 'int'},
    {name: 'Close',     type: 'float'}
  ]
});
```

Sencha Touch:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  config: {
    fields: [
      {name: 'Symbol',    type: 'string'},
      {name: 'LastPrice', type: 'float'},
      {name: 'Bid',       type: 'float'},
      {name: 'Ask',       type: 'float'},
      {name: 'Volume',    type: 'int'},
      {name: 'Close',     type: 'float'}
    ]
  }
});
```

A workaround:

```
var myModelConfig = {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  config: {
    fields: [
      {name: 'Symbol',    type: 'string'},
      {name: 'LastPrice', type: 'float'},
      {name: 'Bid',       type: 'float'},
      {name: 'Ask',       type: 'float'},
      {name: 'Volume',    type: 'int'},
      {name: 'Close',     type: 'float'}
    ]
  }
};
myModelConfig.fields = myModelConfig.config.fields;
Ext.define('MyModel', myModelConfig);
```